# How to add {key: value} using literal_eval in python?

Tags: python

I have a question about how to add a dictionary `{ key: value }` using `literal_eval`.

Well, I have a list of dictionary read from SQL Server.

Like this:

**[Before]**

```
df['col1']

[{'key': 'cat', 'value': 33}, {'key': 'dog', 'value': 10}, {'key': 'flower', 'value': 5},..., {'key': 'house', 'value': 3}]
```

And I this list type converted to dict type using literal_eval.

I want to add new element about 'type'.

Like this,

**[After]**

```
[{'key': 'cat', 'value': 33, 'type': 1}, {'key': 'dog', 'value': 10, 'type': 1}, {'key': 'flower', 'value': 5, 'type': 2},..., {'key': 'house', 'value': 3, 'type': 3}]
```

I'm using for-loop code about normal add dictionary key.

But, It doesn't working.

**[Code example]**

```
for i in range(0, len(df['col1'])):
    ast.literal_eval(df['col1'][i])['type'] = 1
```

Please, tell me the solution this issue.

Comment: What determines the value of `type`?

Comment: I see `df` being used. Are you working with Pandas?

Comment: "literal_eval" what how and why? It's a list of dictionaries, converting it to a dictionary through eval seems both impossible and pointless. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @ddejohn Yes, right. Actually I'm working with Pandas. And this case I extracted one sample for explain to case.

Comment: @Jab It's mean... {'type': 'value'}

Comment: @LennartRegebro I have a dataframe included two columns. And one column has dictionary list like Before case. Well, I want to append different key called 'type' like After case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need `ast.literal_eval` here?

Just use:

```
for i in range(len(list_B)):
    list_B[i]['type'] = 1
```

Or I suggest using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> [{**x, 'type': 1} for x in list_B]
[{'key': 'cat', 'value': 33, 'type': 1}, {'key': 'dog', 'value': 10, 'type': 1}, {'key': 'flower', 'value': 5, 'type': 1}]
>>>
```

Or just with a loop:

```
for i in list_B:
    i['type'] = 1
```

Comment: type doesn't seem to have any logical incrementation or assignment if you look closer. BTW long time no see Forward

Comment: @Jab Hey Jab, long time no chat!

Comment: @Jab Yeah so I specified `1` for type

Comment: @U12-Forward Thank you, Because I read this data from MSSQL. So first type is str.

Comment: @U12-Forward I edited article. please check it.

Comment: @bonbon it should work, try it